# Png background turns black after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, png

When i am trying to upload a png image, after uploading the images the transparent part of the image turns into black...

I would like to know howto fix this problem, any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in  advance..

Regards

Shabir Gilkar

Comment: If you're altering the image on the server (with PHP's GD library, for example), it will turn any transparent areas black. We need to know what language you're using on the server, and any code you have. Also, you need _much_ more information in your question; you can have all the ingredients, but you can't make a cake without a recipe.

Comment: @JamWaffles 

It is Asp.Net project where we use C# as its language, I have a simple form where i ask user to submit his company's logo, When i m trying to simply upload the png files, after uploading it turns its transparent part into black. One thing i would like to note here that i have kept a defined image size of 80x80 pxls in Img tag irrespective of its original size...

Comment: What browser are you using?  Try a different one, if you are not altering the image server side then consider that this could be as simple as the uploaded image has alpha that is not compatible with how it is being rendered.

Comment: Please post relevant code for uploading, maybe you're also manipulating the uploaded file thus ruining it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of inconsistencies that can cause that. Check out [imagecolortransparent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) and [imagealphablending](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php) functions.

You can also do the upload raw without a filter, but there may be consequences of that (e.g. storing `$_FILE` directly without GD processing). If that *is* what you're doing, a bit more detail wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Shabir is actually using ASP.net. I won't -1 due to that info being in the comments and **not in the original question**.